# Grunt - get current calling folder, and not gruntfile current folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

If I have Grunt installed in some folder /foo, but my current folder is /foo/bar/baz, and I run "grunt sometask" from within my current folder, how can I get Grunt (or NodeJS for that matter) to determine my current path? That is to say, how can I programmatically GET the folder I was in when I called grunt?

When I use process.cwd(), I get the path of the gruntfile, ie, "foo", which is not what I want.

I don't have to do this in Grunt specifically, any nodejs-based solution would work.

Comment: [__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)?

Comment: Neither __dirname or __filename will work I'm afraid, they return the current script's location, so that's still the gruntfile or the grunt plugin.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/cli.js#L49):

> By default, all file paths are relative to the Gruntfile

And, *voilá*, [this line of code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/c6b534a7bc2e0a521f1fccf4963e58d58d3009e3/lib/grunt/task.js#L443) shows how grunt actually changes the current directory to the path of the Gruntfile:

```
process.chdir(grunt.option('base') || path.dirname(gruntfile));
```

However, option `--base` is there for just that. See docs: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file

If you don't need to do it **from inside** the Gruntfile, simply run a script that captures the `process.cwd()` and then `execs` grunt.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec

```
var exec = require('exec');

process.cwd(); // Will have your current path

exec(['grunt', 'mytask'], function(err, out, code) {
  if (err instanceof Error)
    throw err;
  process.stderr.write(err);
  process.stdout.write(out);
  process.exit(code);
});
```

Comment: But wouldn't this require that I called grunt with --base some_path, and then manually called grunt.file.setBase(some_path)? I don't want to set the current path, I want to get it.

Comment: Your current path *is set* by grunt. When you get it and it outputs the path where Gruntfile is, it's correct. It's no longer where you invoked grunt. So, if you want to FORCE it to be where you invoked, you need to `--base`.

Comment: using --base expects a path value after it, please check my question , that's not what I asked for.

Also, using --base entirely changes the location context grunt runs in, I don't want to do that, I just want to read a path.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use `--base .`. I understood your question. What I'm trying to say is: there is **no way** to get the path where you ran Grunt **because grunt uses `chdir`**.

Comment: If you don't need to get the path from inside grunt, you can call grunt with exec. I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @firstdoit. I couldn't get this to work as required in Grunt, but it was pretty easy writing a global NodeJS module that did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Have you seen my second suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

in the Mac or Linex, you can get this by

```
process.env.PWD
```

in the windows, unknown

You can edit the grunt-cli to get finish this.

> grunt-cli/bin/grunt

```js
require(gruntpath).cli({_originDir:basedir});
```

then in the gruntfile.js, you can follows:

```js
grunt.option('_originDir')
```